# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129) Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

We are using a Python code to retrieve information from the AWS cost management console and generate charts using Plotly and Chart Studio. However, we have encountered an issue two days ago, specifically the error message **[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate.**

```
Exception has occurred: PlotlyError
Sign in failed.
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.plotly.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/users/current (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I have attempted various solutions found on the internet (updating certifi package, etc), but none of them have worked so far. We are using **Python version 3.9.6** and our operating system is **Windows**. Could someone please provide some assistance with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I usually encounter this error when running python code against aws and I have logged in locally using aws sso, then I just restart my browser and problem is gone. Not sure if it applies to your case though. As for the reason why this happens, i have no idea :)